# Convolution of a $L^p$ function and a $L^q$ function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Let $0\le p\le \infty$ and $q$ be conjugate exponents. $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ and $g\in L^q(\mathbb R^n)$. To prove $f*g$ is bounded, do I need to prove $f*g$ is bounded from above and from below?

My attempt: \begin{align*}
(f*g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-t)g(t)dt
&\le \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x-t)g(t)|dt\\
&\le \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x-t)|^pdt\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |g(t)|^q dt\right)^{1/q}\\
&=\left(-\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x-t)|^p d(x-t) \right)^{1/p}\left(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |g(t)|^q dt\right)^{1/q}\\
&=(-1)^{1/p}||f||_p||g||_q\\
&<+\infty.
\end{align*}
Is the third line correct?

Should I also prove $f*g$ is bounded from below? How to proceed?

Comment: Lebesgue measure is invariant under translations and therefore $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x-t)|^pdt =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(t)|^pdt $.

Comment: You need to show that $|f*g(x)|\le c$.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Got you, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Also if you want to show that $f*g$ is a bounded function it suffices to show that $|(f*g)(x)|<\infty$ for all $x$, and it looks like you already did this.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Right. I just need to add $|\cdot|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line of your proof is indeed correct, as pointed out by @Alonso Delfin in comment above that Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.

Your proof has also shown correctly that $f*g$ is bounded.